# Regexp finding string enclosed by quotes

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2010

I have a little problem with VS2010. 
So I want to find a certain strings between quotes with a Regexpression but only if the line doesn't contain a single "tr" or "QObject::tr" example:

I want to display all this lines:

```
Hallotr("asa");

("hhajkshjkas");

(    _"hhajkshjkas" );
```

But don't want to display this lines:

```
tr("hhajkshjkas");

QObject::tr("hhajkshjkas");
```

My Regexp looks like this:

`[^t-r]"[a-zA-Z0-9<>=\\"" ]*` and `^[^tr]*"[a-zA-Z0-9<>=\\"" ]*"`

but it shows all lines even if there is a single tr on the beginning of the string. Or it shows only lines which don't contain tr.

Thanks for help guys.

Comment: Try `^(?!.*(?:QObject::)?tr).*"[^"]*myvalue[^"]*"`

Comment: thanks for the quick respons but it doesn't work :(

Comment: Okay well it works for http://www.regexpal.com/ and it works right the way I want it so thanks in the first place. But it just doesn't seem to work in Visual Studio 2010. Same goes for regex101.com

Comment: I do not have VS2010, its regex syntax is weird. Something like `^~(.*(QObject::)?tr).*"[^"]*myvalue[^"]*"` might work.

Comment: Starting with Visual Studio 2012, VS uses [.NET Framework regular expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs.aspx). Before that, Visual Studio used a custom regular expression syntax. See [Comparing.NET Framework Regular Expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs(v=vs.110).aspx) for a conversion table.

Comment: @GlennPhilipSchilling, any feedback?

Comment: Hey guys well i got this `^~(.*tr).*:q` this is as near i could get the problem is, that it wount show things like trtest ("value") or testtr("value") the :q stands for "Matches any string inside single or double quotes." With this: `^~(.*(QObject::)?tr)` I get an error which says that I am missing a ')', sorry for the late feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got the solution this is my regexp. :

`^~((.*QObject.+tr)|(:b*tr:b*\()).*:q`